# Multi-dimensional array as function parameter

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to find a way to pass a multi-dimensional array to my `Function` in VBA. I tried google but didn't find anything to help me on my way.

This is what I tried:

```
Public Function getData(Query()() As String) As Integer
```

But that only resulted in a direct error from the enviroment saying it expects a delimiter or ')'.

Comment: :) Show me how you declared your `Query()()` array please

Comment: My question is how can I pass a multi-dimensional Array to a function in VBA. So I would need to know how to do that to. Thanks for trying to help @mehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

`Query()() as String` is not a valid *expression* in VBA.

---

This is how you would create a 2D array in VBA and how to write a function that accept it

```
Sub Main()

    Dim arr(0 To 1, 0 To 1) As String
    arr(0, 0) = "element 0,0"
    arr(1, 0) = "element 1,0"
    arr(0, 1) = "element 0,1"
    arr(1, 1) = "element 1,1"

    Call GetData(arr)

End Sub


Function GetData(myArray() As String) As Integer

End Function
```

and a 3D+ version

```
Sub Main()

    Dim arr(0 To 1, 0 To 1, 0 To 1) As String
    arr(0, 0, 0) = "element 0,0,0"
    arr(1, 0, 0) = "element 1,0,0"
    arr(0, 1, 0) = "element 0,1,0"
    arr(0, 1, 1) = "element 0,1,1"
    arr(0, 0, 1) = "element 0,0,1"
    arr(1, 0, 0) = "element 1,0,0"
    arr(1, 1, 0) = "element 1,1,0"
    arr(1, 0, 1) = "element 1,0,1"
    arr(1, 1, 1) = "element 1,1,1"

    Call GetData(arr)

End Sub


Function GetData(myArray() As String) As Integer

End Function
```